# spring cache not retrieving the value from Map though it exist

Tags: spring, ehcache, spring-cache

I am trying to add data into cache at runtime and retrieve it. I am able to successfully add the data into HashMap but when I invoke findbyIndex method I am getting null value though the key exist in Map. Below is the code:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.cache.annotation.CacheConfig;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.CachePut;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@CacheConfig(cacheNames = { "cachetest" })
public class CacheService {

   private static Map<String, String> store = new HashMap<String, String>();

   @CachePut
   public void putData(String dataid, String data) {
      System.out.println("Executing put data...");
      store.put(dataid, data);
   }

   @Cacheable
   public String findByIndex(String dataid) {
      System.out.println(":Executing findByIndex ...");
      for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : store.entrySet()) {
         System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " : " + entry.getValue());
      }
      return store.get(dataid);
   }

}
```

my ehcache.xml for this cacheconfig is :

```
<cache alias="cachetest">
        <expiry>
            <ttl unit="seconds">5</ttl>
        </expiry>
        <heap unit="entries">1500</heap>
        <jsr107:mbeans enable-statistics="true" />
    </cache>
```

Cache Configuration file:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCache;
import org.springframework.cache.support.SimpleCacheManager;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CachingConfig {
   @Bean
   public CacheService customerDataService() {
       return new CacheService();
   }

   @Bean
   public CacheManager cacheManager() {
       SimpleCacheManager cacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
       cacheManager.setCaches(Arrays.asList(
         new ConcurrentMapCache("cachetest")));
       return cacheManager;
   }
}
```

when a new value is added to store map using putData method the value is successfully getting added to HashMap, but if I try to fetch the value for that newly added data by calling findByIndex method, The method is returning null value though it exist. Any idea whats happening below?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is an incorrect expectation of the behaviour of `@CachePut`. As you can read [in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/CachePut.html) the annotation will use the method parameters to compute the cache key and the method return value to compute the cache value.

So you need to rework your usage of the annotation or the signature of your method.